# Is it ok to use a function/object if defined further down page

Tags: javascript, scope

Eg in a javascript file can I have:

```
var cat = null;

function init() {
   cat = new Cat();
   alert(cat.getLegs());
}

function Cat() {
    this.legs = 4;
}

 Cat.prototype.getLegs = function() { return this.legs; }
```

JSLint complains at this.  But then JSLint does seem to complain at little things that don't seem important.  But it seems to work for me in Chrome.  Do some hosts, eg web browsers complain at this?

Comment: *JSLint does seem to complain at little things that don't seem important.* Ah, but this is important. Function expressions are not subject to hoisting, so you can call neither `init()` nor `Cat()` from the global scope before the latter is evaluated. (Well, you can call `init()`, but it will fail.)

Comment: `Cat` is a named function expression (but *why*?!), and may cause some cross browser issues. Obligatory reading: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Comment: @user, the code in your question has changed drastically, so my previous comment does not apply anymore, however, JSLint is still warning you about the same issue: `Cat.prototype.getLegs()` is assigned a function expression that will not be hoisted, so it is possible for `init()` to be called and refer to it before it actually exists.

Comment: The function of jslint is not to check if your JS syntax is correct - you test THAT each time your code is run. jslint was made to check if you write GOOD (maintainable, readable) code - it is "opinionated" as the author says. Just as in real life - you can legally screw people in lots of ways, this is different from the question if you SHOULD.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi When you say assigned an expression that will not be hoisted, what do you mean?  Do you mean not parsed by browser/js interpreter yet because further down page?

Comment: @user, something like that. Hoisted functions and variables are accessible in the whole scope (as if they were defined at the beginning of that scope). Functions expressions are not hoisted, so they're only accessible from the point of their definition onwards.